# Had I not retrieved those two soiled, damp and moth-eaten books from the garbage pile going to be reduced soon to ashes, I would have remained unknown

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Is the sentence grammatically correct? Should I add 'which was' after the garbage pile

Comment: "Had I not retrieved those two soiled, damp and moth-eaten books from the garbage pile – soon to be reduced to ashes – I would have remained unknown." The sentence is IMO too complicated without making a clear break like this. The future of the garbage pile isn't relevant to the meaning of the sentence, only what was nearly lost.

Comment: Please include the example sentence in the body of the question, not just in the title. See [Asking Questions]("https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785#4785") from the [*Contrinutors Guide*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners)

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence

> Had I not retrieved those two soiled, damp and moth-eaten books from the garbage pile going to be reduced soon to ashes, I would have remained unknown.

is grammatically valid, and does not require the addition of "*which was*" after the words "garbage pile". However the [comment by Weather Vane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324159/had-i-not-retrieved-those-two-soiled-damp-and-moth-eaten-books-from-the-garbage#comment610529_324159) has a point. The sentence is rather complex, and might be confusing for a reader or listener. Separating off the phrase about the garbage pile is one way to make thiu easier. Whether Vane's suggestion:

> Had I not retrieved those two soiled, damp and moth-eaten books from the garbage pile – soon to be reduced to ashes – I would have remained unknown.

is one good idea. Another possibility would be:

Had I not retrieved those two soiled, damp, and moth-eaten books, plucking them from from the garbage pile, soon to be reduced to ashes, I would have remained unknown.